# Find creation time for list elements (including documents)

Tags: splistitem

I know SharePoint has some hidden fields for list items. I need to check the timestamp for when a list element was created, is this possible?

The reason is I must allow the item to be edited for the first 10 minutes after creation, but not after that (through an item receiver).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers work, but you may want to consider:

`item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Created];`

I'm never sure what happens to the default field names in non-English language setups.

Comment: The CSOM `ListItem` object doesn't support Guid indexor. Must use the `["Created"]` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Each item has a created date and modified date which you can get through the indexer.

```
item["Created"];
```

Answer (score 5):

The item["Created"] field will store the date and time that item was created. Cast it to a DateTime type to do your comparison.